# Is it possible to store custom object in Map()?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have response by type:

```
interface IDictionaryKey {
    text: string;
}


let data = response<IDictionaryKey>[];
```

Is it possible to set whole response to`new Map()`?

Something like that:

```
dictionary = new Map<IDictionaryKey[]>();
```

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't it?

Comment: So, I can store any structure inside Map? like `{key: {  key: IDictionaryKey[]}}` ?

Comment: The value of a Map entry can be any JavaScript value. The key can be any value also, but be aware that object keys can only be retrieved by using the *exact same object* as the key, not simply an object that "looks the same".

Comment: Could I assign whole array of objects to map?

Comment: Or iterate one by one and set?

Comment: Yep. But read the @Pointy's remark.

Comment: @OPV a value is a value is a value. If it can appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression (`x = something`), it can be a value in a Map instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set whole response to `new Map()`. I see following options:

1. Full response array will go to single element of `Map`. This makes sence if you're going to receive additional responses of type `IDictionaryKey[]` and store them in `dictionary`. (Like `reponse2`, `response3` and so on).

   ```
   let data: IDictionaryKey[] = response<IDictionaryKey>[];
   let dictionary = new Map<string, IDictionaryKey[]>();
   dictionary.set("response1", data);
   // Now you can retriev first response by 
   let response1 = dictionary.get("response1");
   ```
2. Each element of response array will go to single element of the `Map`. Here is one problem. `IDictionaryKey` interface contain only one property, `text`. For `Map` to be useful it's better to have at least two properties, one will be key, another - value. But `IDictionaryKey` can be stroed in `Map` even with one property.

   ```
   let data: IDictionaryKey[] = response<IDictionaryKey>[];
   let dictionary = new Map<IDictionaryKey, any>();
   data.forEach(d => dictionary.set(d, "" as any));
   // As a result, Map will have only keys. All values will be empty strings
   // Now you can retrive element by
   let elem: IDictionaryKey = {text: "something"};
   let dictionaryElement = dictionary.get(elem); 
   // dictionaryElement will always be either "" or undefined
   ```

   Surely, you can manipulate with `data` array to add it to `Map` in different way. For example

   ```
   let dictionary = new Map<string, IDictionaryKey>();
   data.forEach(d => dictionary.set(d.text, d));
   // And get each element from Map only by text property
   let dictionaryElement: IDictionaryKey = dictionary.get("MyText");
   ```

And last tip. `Map` has contructor, so it is possible to fill `Map` during contruction.

```
let dictionary = new Map<IDictionaryKey, any>(data.map<[IDictionaryKey, any]>(d => [d, "" as any]));
```